# What does "pip uninstall ansible" normally return if there's no ansible in first place?

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I typed in `pip uninstall ansible` and got this

```
~ pip uninstall ansible
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

What does this mean? A few weeks ago, I typed in exactly the same command and got a different output.

```
 ~ pip uninstall ansible
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.
```

My mentor told me that it's normal since there's no ansible installed.

How do I fix the problem with the pip3 stuff?

Could it have something to do with the steps I did earlier:

1. uninstall ansible
2. check if ansible isn't installed with `pip uninstall ansible`
3. add `alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3` to `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
4. type in `sudo -H pip install ansible`

but later I encountered some problem with a project after vagrant up so I thought I'll have to start over again to make sure everything is working...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aliased `pip` to a missing binary

Besides that, you should never be using sudo with pip unless you intend to run Python as root user